# A function can be extended to a uniformly continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $S$ be a subset of the metric space $E$ with the property that
>   each point of $S^c$  is a cluster point of $S.$ Let $E'$ be a complete
>   metric space and $f: S\to E'$ a uniformly continuous function. Prove
>   that $f$ can be extended to a continuous function from $E$ into $E'$
>   in one and only one way, and that this extended function is also
>   uniformly continuous.

Let $s \in S^c$ then since $s$ is a cluster point of $S$ then there is a sequence $s_n \in S$ that converges to $s$ thus the sequence $s_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous and $E'$ is complete we have that $f(x_n)$ is also a Cauchy sequence which converges in $E'$ to some $x.$

How can I now porve that $f$ can be extended, in one and only one way, to a continuous function from $E$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continue along the same lines : Define a function $g:E\to E'$ as follows :

a) If $s \in S$, write $g(s) = f(s)$

b) If $s\in S^c$, choose a sequence $s_n \to s$, with $s_n \in S$, and then you know that $f(s_n)$ converges in $E'$, so define
$$
g(s) = \lim f(s_n)
$$

Now you need to show that this definition of $g(s)$ is independent of choice of $s_n$. This will be an extension of $f$, and it will be unique since $S$ is dense in $E$

Comment: Why define $g(s) = f(s)$? I know $g(s)$ will be the unique limit for $f(s_n)$ but what is $f(s)$ and how $g(s)$ and $f(s)$ related?

Comment: @Tom : $f$ is already defined on $S$, so for any $s\in S, f(s)$ makes sense. You want $g$ to be equal to $f$ on $S$ (this is what it means to extend a function on $S$)

Comment: I didn't understand what it meant to extend a function but thank you very much!

Comment: Prahlad, would this be true if it were not uniformly continuous instead just continuous?

Comment: @Tom : No. the sequence $f(s_n)$ would not be Cauchy if $f$ were just continuous. For instance think of $f(x) = 1/x$ on $(0,1] \subset [0,1]$ - there is no continuous extension to $[0,1]$